Which supervillain is associated with the "who@whocares.com" email address in the Kingpin's doomsday party invitation?
In the 2015 Secret Wars #1 comic book, Wilson Fisk, also known as the Kingpin, sent out email invitations to several supervillains to join him in celebrating the impending end of the world. The comic panel reveals five email addresses, and most of them are fairly straightforward to decipher (please correct me if I'm wrong, though):

lizard@coldblooded.com: Likely belongs to Dr. Curtis Connors, better known as the Lizard.
hitthetarget@hit.com: Likely the email address of the deadly marksman Bullseye, whose presence at the doomsday party is evident from the accompanying panels.
who@whocares.com: This one remains a mystery.
oz@amazinghair.net: Likely a reference to Norman Osborn (the Green Goblin) and his distinctive hairstyle. Norman can be seen attending the party.
wfisk@fiskindustries.com: Obviously Wilson Fisk's own email address.


Unfortunately for the supervillains, the Punisher also got the memo...
While the identities behind four email addresses seem apparent, I cannot decipher the supervillain associated with the who@whocares.com address. Can any fellow True Believers identify who this supervillain might be?

I've seen a few comments online that say it could be Chameleon

@Fez - I was just going to comment the same. It's a fairly simple process of elimination that OP has already done.

You can tell he's a villain because he didn't use BCC.
